# Getting an error once i try to add an app to my site

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app

I am getting the following error after i added the app to the app catalog.
The specified application identifier * is invalid or does not exist.
I have no idea whats wrong. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

So basically i didnt realize i had to go into the webconfig and appmanifest.xml to change the clientid="//randomNumberGeneratedGoesHere", you get this from from the ~/_layouts/15/appnewreg.aspx page

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the hosting type in `AppManifest.xml` from Provider-hosted to SharePoint-hosted and voilá.

I don't know if this was modified by itself when I added an Event Receiver in my project, cause before not fails.

[image]